# Animate alpha from View's StartX to EndX (Growing horizontal Bar)

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

Current animation changes alpha for **every part** of view. I want to change the alpha through view's x and y positions. *Think it as a growing horizontal bar*. I have a view which is drawn by myself (`canvas`). Also the issue is this drawn views are in list view, they are the listview elements. So probably i need to animate ListView itself not the elements to achieve desired outcome

How can i achieve it?

Comment: first of all you need to read about PorterDuff xfer modes (most likely SRC_IN / DST_IN ones). then you should apply `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` to animate your view

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you give me good sources on that?

Comment: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html or http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mer0918/index.html or just ask google for `porterduff`

Comment: Thanks. By the way you understand the question rite? Growing horizontal bar part. For example at start the view's width will be 0 (but not scaled width) and then it will grow to its actual width in two seconds for example. It is like closing view with paper and translating paper position as time goes by

Comment: if it is not too much to ask, can you give me example. Elements are in listview. Will i do that in listview adapter getview or in listview's fragment?